# The best layout for this image?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, layout-manager

I don't know which is the best layout to use for this image, I think maybe grid layout (5*1) may be helpful but I can't add multiple components in one grid layout cell.

Here's the GUI:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use `BoxLayout` vertically with one column of five `JPanel` to which all the other components have been added without changing the layout manager ( `FlowLayout`) of `JPanel`

Answer (score 1):

The sections of that column the Currency Exchange GUI seem to be of equal height, which would suggest a single column `GridLayout`. For unequal height sections, perhaps a `GridBagLayout` or a `BoxLayout` as suggested in the comments.

Each of the sections themselves looks to be a default `FlowLayout`, with a line of components centered with some padding between.